# Julia documentation "Load key: invalid format"

Tags: github, julia, documentation

I followed the hosting documentation (Documenter.jl) to deploy the documentation for the TSSOS Julia package. But I got the following error in the workflow (GitHub Actions):

```
Failed to add the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.112.3' to the list of known hosts (/home/runner/.ssh/known_hosts).
Load key "/home/runner/work/TSSOS/TSSOS/docs/.documenter": invalid format
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
┌ Error: Git failed to fetch git@github.com:wangjie212/TSSOS.git
│ This can be caused by a DOCUMENTER_KEY variable that is not correctly set up.
│ Make sure that the environment variable is properly set up as a Base64-encoded string
│ of the SSH private key. You may need to re-generate the keys with DocumenterTools.
└ @ Documenter ~/.julia/packages/Documenter/FuXcO/src/Documenter.jl:554
```

Any idea to fix this issue? I use the Windows 10 system and the key pair was generated by `DocumenterTools.genkeys`.

Comment: Did you give the key write permissions? Default is read-only.

Comment: Yes, I gave the write permission.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it looks like the wrong place for secrets was used. When you enter secrets there are two options: Environment secrets and Repository secrets. In new github interface it's rather hard to find where you can add Repository secrets, but it's possible still. It is in `settings/secrets` and you have to create an environment first. After you create environment, you should again click to `secrets` and there is an almost invisible button in the middle of the interface "New repository secret". You should place `DOCUMENTER_KEY` there and everything will run smoothly.